# how to distinguish data-handling from 2 forms with 1 ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have 2 different forms and i want to handle the data of these forms with 1 ajax to the php file.
To distinguish if it is a `main-comment-form` or a `nested-comment-form`, i put an extra hidden input with the value `main_form` the the first form field:

**Main form** (for normal comment):

```
<form class="commentform" action="" method="POST" role="form">
    <!-- MAIN_COMMENT; need to distinguish main comment or nested comment -->
    <input type="hidden" class="main_comment" value="true" />
    <!-- NAME -->
    <input class="form-control comment_name" name="comment_name" type="text" placeholder="NAME">    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_comment">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**2nd form** (for posting nested comment)

```
<form class="commentform" action="" method="POST" role="form">
    <!-- NESTED NAME -->
    <input class="form-control nested_comment_name" name="nested_comment_name" type="text" placeholder="NAME">  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_nested_comment">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My ajax js looks like this:

```
$('.commentform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var main_comment = $(".main_comment").val();    
    var comment_name = $(".comment_name").val();        
    var nested_comment_name = $(".nested_comment_name").val();


    $.ajax({
        url: 'comment.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
                main_comment:main_comment,          
                comment_name:comment_name,                              
                nested_comment_name:nested_comment_name,

                },
```

The PHP file, comment.php:

```
// variables
$main_comment = $_POST['main_comment'];
echo $main_comment;
```

When i post from the 2nd form (nested comment), it also echo's the value `true`.
I do not understand this, because in the 2nd form, i do not send `$_POST['main_comment']`

Comment: But there is a form field called `main_comment` within a form class of `commentform`, because you have two forms of the same class and you don't distinguish between them. It can therefore find the field you're using. What happens if you put a field in your second form called `main_comment` and set the value to `false`? Or maybe use `this` to identify the form that you're using? (I'm not big on JS, but you need to distinguish between the two forms somehow)

Comment: When i put the hidden field with value "false" in the second form, in both form submits it echo's `true`.

Comment: OK, so it must be finding the first entry and using that. That probably makes sense. So you will need to code it to refer to the form that actually calls the Ajax code. I've no idea how, but maybe `$(this).$(".main_comment").val() ` or something like it?

Comment: I solved the problem with 2 different ajax

Comment: Well, that's OK, but it's duplication where it is not needed. Another way is to use something like `var postdata = $(this).serializeArray();` and submit `postdata` to your form. That should take all form fields from the form that calls the submit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of thinking to solve this problem with a hidden field is good.
But you have to put also a hidden field on the second form with the value `false`

1st form:

```
<form class="commentform" action="" method="POST" role="form">
    <!-- CHECK_MAIN_COMMENT; need to distinguish main comment or nested comment -->
    <input type="hidden" class="main_comment" value="true" />
    <!-- NAME -->
    <input class="form-control comment_name" name="comment_name" type="text" placeholder="NAME">    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_comment">Submit</button>
</form>
```

2nd form:

```
<form class="commentform" action="" method="POST" role="form">
    <!-- CHECK_MAIN_COMMENT; need to distinguish main comment or nested comment -->
    <input type="hidden" class="main_comment" value="false" />
    <!-- NESTED NAME -->
    <input class="form-control nested_comment_name" name="nested_comment_name" type="text" placeholder="NAME">  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_nested_comment">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Your ajax:

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // below;this will find the value of class main_comment from the CLOSEST form!
    var main_comment = $(this).closest('.comment_form').find('.main_comment').val(); 

    var comment_name = $(".comment_name").val();        
    var nested_comment_name = $(".nested_comment_name").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'comment.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
                main_comment:main_comment,          
                comment_name:comment_name,                              
                nested_comment_name:nested_comment_name,

                },
```

comment.php

```
// variables
$main_comment = $_POST['main_comment'];

if($main_comment == 'true') {
    // handle data that comes from 1st form
}
else {
    // handle data that comes from 2nd form
}
```

Comment: Works great this way! Thnx